# Optimization in sql server query

Tags: sql, sql-optimization

My Below query in my stored procedure takes more time.Is there any way to optimize this below query.Input parameters are Name and CA.

```
SELECT @E_ID=vb.e_id
FROM VALUES va, mappings im, VALUES va2
WHERE im.pv_name=vb.value
AND va.E_ID in (select e_id from listings where id = 200)  
AND va.f_id=100
AND va2.f_id=101 AND va.e_id=va2.e_id
AND im.w_i_name='"'+@NAME+'"' AND va2.value='["'+@CA+'"]'
ORDER BY va.e_id
```

Comment: You should have a look into the execution plan, there you see which operation costs how much and than you can optimize

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We see now that contrary to the popular opinion, IN / EXISTS queries are not less efficient than a JOIN query in SQL Server. But JOIN queries are less efficient on non-indexed tables. I'm not sure, but you can modify as following this:

```
SELECT @E_ID=vb.e_id
FROM VALUES va, mappings im, VALUES va2
join (select e_id from listings where id = 200) tmp on tmp.e_id = va.E_ID
WHERE im.pv_name=vb.value
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is to make sure is that every single field mentioned in the WHERE clause and in the ORDER BY clause is indexed.

The second thing I would do is try the following:

```
...
LEFT JOIN listings on va.E_ID = listings.e_id WHERE listings.id = 200
...
```

(Though I would be surprised if the query optimizer does not take care of this.)

The third thing I would do is try the following:

```
...
(SELECT * FROM VALUES WHERE f_id=100) va, 
(SELECT * FROM VALUES WHERE f_id=101) va2,
...
```